# Message box on server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have button click handler event in which i am using if-else condition.How can i show a message if it runs to else statement?
Like please fill the requirements!!.

Comment: You have to fill the requirements.. not us :)

Comment: Message box *on the server side*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) method:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "someKey", "alert('oops');", true);
```

But for this kind of things probably it's better to use validation controls (can't say for sure as you haven't specified any context nor explained the logic).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `javascript` in .cs

```
Page.ClientScriptBlock.RegisterStartupScript(Page. GetType(), "Key", "alert('message');", true);
```